# Problems connecting to MySQL - Error 2003 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Problem:

Using mysql -u  -h  -p I can connect with localhost but cannot connect with external IP

I check connection for both localhost and external IP where MySQL is installed

What I have set up:

- user with host as % (accepts everything)
- granted user with host as % (all privileges)
- flushed privileges
- restarted mysql
- checked tablesip and ufw

Any help would be appreciated :) 3 days and counting.

Answer (score 0):

Comment the bind address `127.0.0.1` in mysql configuration file on your remote server.

Generally the file is located at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

on `ubuntu` system.

EDIT: Restart MySql after done.

Comment: Thanks for reply - commented out bind-address and restarted MySQL, also did a sudo reboot and tried again after reboot.

I still get connection refused (111)

Any other way to test this, logs or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Success! Oh my gosh.. there we're two bind address I had to comment out!!

So what I did:

1. netstat -l Checks to see what IP MySQL is listening to
2. Checked my.cnf and other linked cnf files
3. Commented out second bind-address
4. Done!